# How to return multiple updates of a JSON using expressjs and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, fetch-api

I have a server side task that takes some time to compute, and I'd like to periodically send updates to the client. I store and send the information as an object (via JSON), and it isn't an array where I can send data sequentially. Rather, I want to send some new information, and update others as the calculation continues.

From other posts on here I realize that:

`response.json(object)` is a nice and easy way to send an object json in one go, with headers set and everything. However, this - like `response.send()` - terminates the connection:

```
var app = express()
app.get('/', (request, response) => {
  response.json( { hello:world } );
})
```

Alternatively, one could set the headers manually, and then use `response.write` with `JSON.stringify`

```
response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
response.write(JSON.stringify({ hello:world } ));
response.end();
```

The above two methods work for sending an object in one go, but ideally what I'd like to do is send incremental updates to my object. E.g.

```
response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
response.write( JSON.stringify( { hello:[world], foo:bar } ) );
// perform some operations
response.write( JSON.stringify( { hello:[world, anotherWorld], foo:cat } ) );
response.end()
```

However, what is happening on the clientside is:

1. After the first `response.write`, the client receives `{ hello:[world], foo:bar }` **but does not trigger my callback**
2. After the second `response.write`, I can see the data received is `{ hello:[world], foo:bar }{ hello:[world, anotherWorld], foo:cat }` **still does not trigger my callback**
3. My callback is only called after `response.end()`, and then I get an exception when trying to parse it as JSON, because it isn't a valid JSON anymore, but a bunch of JSONs stuck back to back with no comma or anything: `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column XXX of the JSON data`.

Ideally my client callback would be triggered upon receiving each write, and it would remove that bit of data from the buffer so to speak, so the next incoming json would be standalone.
Is what I want to do possible? If so, how?

My fetch code btw:

```
fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json()) // parse the JSON from the server
    .then(returnInfo => {
        onReturn(returnInfo);
    });
```

Comment: Have you considered using NDJSON? It's like JSON arrays, but it's designed for streaming API use cases. Each line of the response is an entire JSON object. With your methodology, you'd stream new versions of the same line sequentially. You would use the same `JSON.stringify()` function, but you'd append a `\n` after the JSON data. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_streaming#Line-delimited_JSON for details.

Comment: I think that the callback is called only when the response is terminated.  You end up with several chunks of JSON data, but concatenated JSONs are not a valid JSON: `{"a":"b"}{"c":"d"}` ← invalid.

Answer (score 0):

For your use-case, you can consider using WebSockets to deliver incremental updates to your UI. There are 3 stages of WebSockets connections. Connect, message and disconnect. One page load your front-end maintains persistent connection with backend. You can send first JSON data on connect and then when your backend has updates, send data in your message call back. I have written a blog post that implements WebSockets using Python and Javascript. However, you can implement similar logic using NodeJS

https://blog.zahidmak.com/create-standalone-websocket-server-using-tornado/